# Xcode bot integration finishes with "An error occurred updating existing checkout. Falling back to a clean checkout."

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration

Xcode bot integration gives me a warning:

> An error occurred updating existing checkout. Falling back to a clean
>   checkout.

It happens randomly, not on every integration. What can be a cause?

Comment: I'm seeing this too. What's your git server? I'm on BitBucket, seeing this every integration.

Comment: I'm seeing it each time too (just started using XcodeServer a couple days ago) and I'm on Bitbucket too.